# How to check if a number is of the form $2^n - 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Numbers which are of the form $2^n-1$ are $1, 3, 7, 15, 31...$

Can we find directly using a formula that a number is of the form $2^n-1$?

Please help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)  Start by surrounding MathJax commands with $ signs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600293/how-to-check-if-a-number-is-a-power-of-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $k$ be the number in question. $$k=2^n -1$$ $$\therefore k+1=2^n$$ $$\therefore n=\log_2(k+1).$$ If $n$ is a positive integer, then $k$ is in the form of $2^n-1$ for some integer $n\geq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick algorithm you may want to use if you can't be doing with those logarithms.

Let $k$ be the number you start with.

1. Add $1$, to get $k + 1$.
2. Is what you have left an even number? If Yes, go to 3. If not, go to 4.
3. Divide by $2$ and go back to step 2.
4. Is what you have left equal to $1$? If Yes, then $k$ is of the form $2^n - 1$. If No, then $k$ is not of the form $2^n - 1$.

Job done.

This takes $k + 1$ and carries on dividing by $2$ till there are no more $2$s to divide it by. If there's an odd number left that is *not* $1$, it means $k$ is of the form $2^n m - 1$ where $m$ is an odd number. If what you have left *is* $1$, then it means $k$ is of the form $2^n - 1$.